# DQL Subquery Questions

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to SLECT * FROM a table `o` where the vendor is what I pass.(this is in the context of a Doctrine Repository).  I then want to run a subquery and `SELECT * FROM AppBundle:PriceOption` where `p.offer` is `o`.  I'm getting a QueryException when running this code though:

```
public function getVendorFeaturedDeals(Vendor $vendor){
    $purchaseOptions = $this->
        getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('AppBundle:PriceOption', 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.offer', 'o')
        ->getDQL();


    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    return $query
        ->where('o.vendor = :vendor')
        ->addSelect(sprintf('(%s)', $purchaseOptions))
        ->setParameter(':vendor', $vendor)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Here's the error : `AppBundle\Tests\Service\VendorServiceTest::testGetVendorFeaturedDeals
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 18: Error: Unexpected 'FROM'` Caused by `Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT o, (SELECT FROM AppBundle:PriceOption p INNER JOIN p.offer o) FROM AppBundle\Entity\Offer o WHERE o.vendor = :vendor`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the error? I mean the `SELECT FROM` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your query to:

```
$purchaseOptions = $this->
    getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(['p', 'o'])
    ->from('AppBundle:PriceOption', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('p.offer', 'o')
    ->getDQL();
```